# iOS modal view controller rotation is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a problem with modal view controller rotation.

While rotating screen from portrait orientation to landscape, my modal view controller stays portrait, despite of:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    self.view.frame = [self frameWithInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

When I debug, I see, that there is everything normal with view frame. It seems that whole controller is placed wrong after rotation to landscape.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7RhXyt7hwQWSUpjaXZiVjlRMEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: I am not using a interface builder at all...

Comment: @TomKortney, you can define auto-layout in code as well.....

Comment: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is not used in iOS 8.

Comment: what are you doing inside your `frameWithInterfaceOrientation` method. I guess this is the culprit.

Comment: Yea, there is everything OK with this method...